# Magento not sending new order emails

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

All of a sudden Magento (1.9.1.0) stopped sending new order emails automatically.
From backend if I click on Send Email in Sales > Orders > Random Order then the user receive the email, but I have to do it manually.

I checked all the options in Configuration > Sales > Sales emails > Order and Enabled is set to Yes and sender email domain is the same domain of the site.

I have enabled logging in System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings and checked logs files in magento var/log but there's nothing strange.

I also checked mail server logs, there's no trace of automatically sent emails, i only see entries of manually sent emails

Comment: i already tried Ashroeder SMTP Pro as an alternative solution, automatic emails are still not sent

Comment: please test mail() is working or not ?

Comment: tested, mail() is working

Comment: refresh cache and try

Comment: cache refreshing is not the problem

Comment: How often is your cron firing?

Comment: Closing as duplicate. Please edit & update after verifying that scheduled jobs are running via server cron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Magento 1.9.1 sales emails are added to a queue and sent via cron job. You can view the release notes at http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce19-later-release-notes

Once you setup a cron job your store will begin to send order emails again.

Comment: thx eirik, i setup a cron job and now emails are sent